# MEAN app crashed after some queries

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my mongoose config:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.dbhost + config.dbname, function(err){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {
       console.log('connected to the database successfuly.');
   }
});
```

I have a MEAN stack application and it works perfectly and I have a page for adding posts ajaxly by angular 1.5. My problem is my application crashes after adding some posts fastly!! why?

Picture of my project proccesses on my Ubuntu VPS in 10 seconds:
[image]

Comment: Describes `crashes`. What messages do you get ?

Comment: This is my problem too! I don't know how can I see my crach logs. I run it by "nodemon" and there is no error in nodmeon setarter!!!

Comment: Then how do you know that the app crashes ?

Comment: Because I have a form for adding post (angular ajax) and after each add, I added the new Item in to view. But after some add query, suddnly that page does not work and after 5 min, app can work again!!

Comment: Describe `the page does not work`. Is there something in your console ? please use `node` instead of `nodemon` to see if an error message is shown

Comment: I used `node` insted of `nodemon` but there is no message again!!

Comment: Again, what do you mean by **does not work** ? Did you check your browser console ?

Comment: Yes I checked that. I think problem is about mongoose connection or something else !! My connection is open and I did not write any "disconnect" in my server.js

Comment: Thus why do you say `I think` ? Did you see an error message somewhere ? Dude please. Be smart and clear when answering. When I say **did you check the browser console** the answer is not supposed to be **yes**. Please describe what is inside the console. What errors are shown ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean is there is no error or message at all! just my message that is: "App is running and monogo db cnnected"

Comment: There is a chance that your VPS host killed it because of resource overuse like memory. Check OS logs.

Comment: #YOU hod yo help me check OS logs? how can I check that and where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for proper connection error

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

    db.once('open', function callback(){
      console.log('Connected to DB');
    });     

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://'+CONFIG.mongo.user+':'+CONFIG.mongo.pass+'@'+CONFIG.mongo.host+':'+CONFIG.mongo.port+'/'+CONFIG.mongo.db, CONFIG.mongo.options);
```

I have tried this code on production didn't faced any problem, this should help you.

Comment: I tried it but there is no error yet. I attached a picture of proccesses in 10 second of my project on my VPS.